# FXCM cannot connect to sever

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to connect to fxmpy. I tried several tutorials plus the O'reilly Python for Finance instructions but I keep getting errors whatever solution I try.

I downgraded to socket 4.6.1 and I am still getting issues.

**Make sure you have installed the socketio `4.6.1` version. Will not work with the new version**

fxcmpy version 1.2.6

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pylab import mpl, plt
import requests
import fxcmpy
import socket
from socketIO_client import SocketIO`

FXCM_API_TOKEN = '23b0f71eab5b91edd3b38ce15f6885ecxxxxxx'
api = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token = FXCM_API_TOKEN, log_level='error')
```

```
|ERROR|2021-03-15 23:50:29,166|Socket returns unknown error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServerError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9cb4e3797d65> in <module>
     12 
     13 FXCM_API_TOKEN = '23b0f71eab5b91edd3b38ce15f6885ecxxxxxxxx'
---> 14 api = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token = FXCM_API_TOKEN, log_level='error')

~\anaconda3.1\lib\site-packages\fxcmpy\fxcmpy.py in __init__(self, access_token, config_file, log_file, log_level, server, proxy_url, proxy_port, proxy_type)
    216             raise ServerError('Can not find FXCM Server.')
    217         elif self.connection_status == 'aborted':
--> 218             raise ServerError('Can not connect to FXCM Server.')
    219 
    220         self.__collect_account_ids__()

ServerError: Can not connect to FXCM Server.



plt.style.use('seaborn') #plot style
mpl.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300 # resolution of the figures
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif' #font style
%matplotlib inline



from fxcmpy import fxcmpy_tick_data_reader as tdr


print(tdr.get_available_symbols())
```

This part seems to work for some reason as the symbols are retrieved

```
('AUDCAD', 'AUDCHF', 'AUDJPY', 'AUDNZD', 'CADCHF', 'EURAUD', 'EURCHF', 'EURGBP', 'EURJPY', 'EURUSD', 'GBPCHF', 'GBPJPY', 'GBPNZD', 'GBPUSD', 'GBPCHF', 'GBPJPY', 'GBPNZD', 'NZDCAD', 'NZDCHF', 'NZDJPY', 'NZDUSD', 'USDCAD', 'USDCHF', 'USDJPY')
```

and then try to retrieve historical data

```
start = dt.datetime(2021, 2, 20)
stop = dt.datetime(2021, 2, 22)


td = tdr('GBPUSD', start, stop)
```

and now I get a https error:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5298b956609c> in <module>
----> 1 td = tdr('GBPUSD', start, stop)

~\anaconda3.1\lib\site-packages\fxcmpy\fxcmpy_data_reader.py in __init__(self, symbol, start, end, verbosity)
     94         self.codec = 'utf-16'
     95         if not isinstance(self, fxcmpy_candles_data_reader):
---> 96             self.__fetch_data__()
     97 
     98     def get_raw_data(self):

~\anaconda3.1\lib\site-packages\fxcmpy\fxcmpy_data_reader.py in __fetch_data__(self)
    172             year, week, noop = running_date.isocalendar()
    173             url = self.url % (self.symbol, year, week)
--> 174             data = self.__fetch_dataset__(url)
    175             if len(self.data) == 0:
    176                 self.data = data

~\anaconda3.1\lib\site-packages\fxcmpy\fxcmpy_data_reader.py in __fetch_dataset__(self, url)
    183         if self.verbosity:
    184             print('Fetching data from: %s' % url)
--> 185         requests = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    186         buf = BytesIO(requests.read())
    187         f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\anaconda3.1\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found```

Any ideas?
````

Answer (score 0):

Today August 26 - 2022   is working with next version

```
fxcmpy==1.3.3
python-engineio==4.3.1
python-socketio==5.0.4
websocket-client==1.1.0
```

Comment: Still not working for me, urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score -1):

in cmd, but if linux try pip3.

```
pip uninstall fxcmpy 

pip install fxcmpy==1.2.5 ALREADY BUT DO IT AGAIN.
pip uninstall socketio 
pip uninstall python-socketio 
pip install python-socketio==4.6.1
```

Change connection to: nothing else.
fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=TOKEN,log_level='warn',log_file=None)